# Python int too large to convert to C long appears on string

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, dtype

I am trying to save a df as a .parquet file. However I get the error

*Python int too large to convert to C long*

Now I tested which column is the source of the problem and to my surprise it is not an integer at all.
The column contains strings of the following structure:

```
text&R.<Default>.text.Text_Text.Text[56]
```

And the dtype is 'object'. The max length is 85.
I tried using `.astype('|S')` but still the same error when using `df.to_parquet('path//file.parquet')`

Extra info, the df has 70930678 rows.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An [mcve] would help greatly, unless someone has seen that exact error before under the exact same circumstances.

Comment: As error states, your integer is too large. Python can have `int` of arbitrary size, while C longs can be at maximum `LONG_MAX` or 2.147.483.647